# How do i write the following Query in laravel

Tags: sql, laravel, laravel-8

I have this Query which i am trying to execute

```
$other = $this->electricityConnections->select('category_id')
    ->from('building_category_settings')
    ->where('building_id', '=', 52)
    ->where('hide_from_electricity_widget', '=', 1)
    ->groupBy('category_id')
    ->orderBy('kwh_used', 'desc');

$electCategory = $this->electricityConnections
    ->addselect(('MIN(IF(category.description IS NOT NULL, 
    category.description, your_electricity_yesterday_category.cat_desc) 
            as cat_desc'),
        ('SUM(kwh_used) as kwh_used'), ('SUM(cost) as cost'),
        'your_electricity_yesterday_category.category_id')
    ->leftJoin('category as category',
        'your_electricity_yesterday_category.category_id', '=', 'category.id')
    ->where('your_electricity_yesterday_category.category_id', '=', 11)
    ->where('your_electricity_yesterday_category.building_id', '=', 52)
    ->whereNotIn('your_electricity_yesterday_category.category_id', $other)
    ->get();
dd($electCategory);
```

But i keep getting this error

> "message": "SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064
> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
> corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
> near '.`cat_desc)` as `cat_desc`, `SUM(kwh_used)` as `kwh_used`,
> `SUM(cost)` as `cost`' at line 1 (SQL: select
> `MIN(IF(category`.`description IS NOT NULL, category`.`description, your_electricity_yesterday_category`.`cat_desc)` as `cat_desc`,
> `SUM(kwh_used)` as `kwh_used`, `SUM(cost)` as `cost`,
> `your_electricity_yesterday_category`.`category_id` from
> `your_electricity_yesterday_category` left join `category` as
> `category` on `your_electricity_yesterday_category`.`category_id` =
> `category`.`id` where
> `your_electricity_yesterday_category`.`category_id` = 11 and
> `your_electricity_yesterday_category`.`building_id` = 52 and
> `your_electricity_yesterday_category`.`category_id` not in (select
> `category_id` from `building_category_settings` where `building_id` =
> 52 and `hide_from_electricity_widget` = 1 group by `category_id` order
> by `kwh_used` desc))",

When I do `toSql()` to the code above I get the following below

```
"select `MIN(IF(category`.`description IS NOT NULL, category`.`description, your_electricity_yesterday_category`.`cat_desc)` as `cat_desc`, `SUM(kwh_used)` as `kwh_used`, `SUM(cost)` as `cost`, `your_electricity_yesterday_category`.`category_id` from `your_electricity_yesterday_category` left join `category` as `category` on `your_electricity_yesterday_category`.`category_id` = `category`.`id` where `your_electricity_yesterday_category`.`category_id` = ? and `your_electricity_yesterday_category`.`building_id` = ? and `your_electricity_yesterday_category`.`category_id` not in (select `category_id` from `building_category_settings` where `building_id` = ? and `hide_from_electricity_widget` = ? group by `category_id` order by `kwh_used` desc)"
```

What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I think the main problem is the `addSelect` part. You're missing a closing `)` for `MIN`. Try using `DB::raw` when the selected columns include sql functions.

```php
addselect(
    DB::raw('MIN(IF(category.description IS NOT NULL, category.description, your_electricity_yesterday_category.cat_desc)) as cat_desc'),
    DB::raw('SUM(kwh_used) as kwh_used'),
    DB::raw('SUM(cost) as cost'), 
    'your_electricity_yesterday_category.category_id'
)
```

Comment: did that got same error

Comment: What if you use `select` here instead of `addSelect` ?

Answer (score 0):

you are missing parentheses from end of below line

```
MIN(IF(category.description IS NOT NULL, category.description, your_electricity_yesterday_category.cat_desc)) as cat_desc
```

you need to close bracket before **as cat_desc**, this seems to be syntax issue.

Comment: did that still got same error

Comment: can you share error now?

Answer (score 0):

You Can Use `selectRaw`, check docs: https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/queries#selectraw

```
->selectRaw("
    MIN(IF(category.description IS NOT NULL, category.description, your_electricity_yesterday_category.cat_desc)) as cat_desc),
    SUM(kwh_used) as kwh_used,
    SUM(cost) as cost), 
    your_electricity_yesterday_category.category_id               
")
```

Answer (score -1):

**.** is a keyword in SQL. You may not used it as a column name without quoting it. In MySQL, things like column names are quoted using backticks, i.e. . with ``

Personally, I wouldn't bother; I'd just rename the column.

Comment: So how would you write it?

Comment: Using `` and the dot is inside the backticks